# Fancy box z-index and overlapping issues

Tags: jquery, fancybox, z-index

I am new to jquery and using fancy box for the first time. I am having a couple of issues.

When fancybox is open and I scroll, the next photo slides over OUTSIDE of the actual box so it looks like it's coming from the right of the page, not staying inside the fancy box structure.

Also I have my header set to a very hi z-index, and naturally it overlaps the top of the fancy box. How do I use z-index on fancy box when its opened?

Here is my code.

```
.header {
 background:#FFF;
 height:65px;
-webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.49);
 -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.49);
 box-shadow:0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.49);
 position:relative; z-index:1000001;
}

portfolio_photo {
 -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.49);
 -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.49);
 box-shadow:0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.49);
 float:left;
 margin-right:20px;
 width:31%;
 padding:10px;
}

<div class="portfolio_photo">
   <a href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/img/slideshow/slide_1.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery" title="Sample title 1"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/img/slideshow/slide_1.jpg" /></a>
</div>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".fancybox").fancybox({

               });
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

1) That is how v2 works. You can change nextEffect/prevEffect to `fade` if you wish.
2) fancyBox uses z-index starting from 8000. So, either set every z-index of fancyBox to higher or set lower z-index for your header element.